# Undefined Method "each_pair" Error when running DB Migrate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, dbmigrate

here is the error:

Migration Code:

```
class Test < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :test do |t|
    end
  end
end
```

As a side note, it does not fail if i remove the "Create_table" call.

Upon running `rake db:migrate`, I get this error mesage:

```
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

undefined method `each_pair' for []:Array/Users/m/Apps/stream-web/db/migrate/20150329070040_test.rb:3:in `change'
NoMethodError: undefined method `each_pair' for []:Array
/Users/m/Apps/stream-web/db/migrate/20150329070040_test.rb:3:in `change'
```

How might one go about resolving this? I am using the "pg" gem and my adapter is postgresql.

Full trace error:

```
undefined method `each_pair' for []:Array/Users/mingyeowng/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_statements.rb:216:in `create_table'
/Users/mingyeowng/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/schema_plus-1.8.5/lib/schema_plus/active_record/connection_adapters/schema_statements.rb:39:in `create_table_with_schema_plus'
/Users/mingyeowng/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:662:in `block in method_missing'
/Users/mingyeowng/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:632:in `block in say_with_time'
/Users/mingyeowng/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/benchmark.rb:279:in `measure'
/Users/mingyeowng/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:632:in `say_with_time'
/Users/mingyeowng/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:652:in `method_missing'
/Users/mingyeowng/Apps/stream-web/db/migrate/20150329070040_test.rb:3:in `change'
```

Comment: why would you want an empty table? try adding a few columns.

Comment: this is for testing. a few columns created the same error

Comment: does it still fail if you remove the create_table statement?

Comment: no, it does not fail if i remove that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is down to the schema_plus gem you are using: rails 4.2.1 changed the signature of a method it was overriding.

There is a [fix](https://github.com/SchemaPlus/schema_plus/commit/e887cd9c19ed2784873e52086cfb876518d57427) on the master branch, however this [won't be backported](https://github.com/SchemaPlus/schema_plus/issues/210) to the 1.x series of the gem, which doesn't support versions after rails 4.2. You can however use the current 2.0.0 pre-release versions.

Comment: thank you! no way i could have resolved this without your help.